# Conditional filtering in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, if-statement, flask, sqlalchemy, refactoring

I have this monster of a if statement that I use to filter results from database, but it begs to be refactored, is there any way to make filter queries conditional on variable? I need to return recipe belonging to every category/cuisine if it has ID of "1" which is all in my DB.

```
if ingredients_form and any_ingredients == "1":
    if category_form == "1" and cuisine_form == "1":
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form))
            ).all()
    elif category_form == "1":
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form)),
            Recipe.category_id==category_form
            ).all()
    elif cuisine_form == "1":
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form)),
            Recipe.cuisine_id==cuisine_form
            ).all()
    else:
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form)), 
            Recipe.category_id==category_form,
            Recipe.cuisine_id==cuisine_form
            ).all()

elif ingredients_form and any_ingredients == "2":
    if category_form == "1" and cuisine_form == "1":
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form))
            ).all()
    elif category_form == "1":
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form)),
            Recipe.category_id==category_form
            ).all()
    elif cuisine_form == "1":
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form)),
            Recipe.cuisine_id==cuisine_form
            ).all()
    else:
        search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
            Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
            ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form)), 
            Recipe.category_id==category_form,
            Recipe.cuisine_id==cuisine_form
            ).all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import sqlalchemy

def custom_filter_statement(category_form, cuisine_form):
    if category_form == "1" and cuisine_form == "1":
        return sqlalchemy.sql.true()
    elif category_form == "1":
        return Recipe.category_id == category_form
    elif cuisine_form == "1":
        return Recipe.cuisine_id == cuisine_form
    return sqlalchemy.and_(Recipe.category_id==category_form, Recipe.cuisine_id==cuisine_form)

if ingredients_form and any_ingredients in ["1", "2"]:
    search_result2 = Recipe.query.filter(
        Recipe._ingredients.any(Ingredient.id.in_(ingredients_form)),
        ~Recipe._allergens.any(Allergen.id.in_(allergens_form)),
        custom_filter_statement(category_form, cuisine_form)
        ).all()
```

I suggest renaming variables `cuisine_form` to cuisine_id etc. cause naming *_form for variables holding id value is quite misleading.

Also literals `"1"` and `"2"` should be replaced with constants with proper descriptive names so that it is instantly obvious what these values denote.